# sitefinity how to send file to client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I am using Sitefinity w/MVC.  I want a controller for an MVC Component to return a file to the client.  The file is built in memory.  How do I deliver the file to the client from either a byte stream or string?

Thanks.

(I have tried searching for everything I can think of relating to this, but searches are only pulling up files about sitefinity that I can download, instead of help with code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return FileResult like in any other ASP.NET MVC controller action.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    return this.File("C:\\Work\\MyImage.png", "image/png");
}
```